# How come the pound sign '£' in Haskell is shown as '\163' instead of outputting '£'?

Tags: haskell, character-codes

I'm trying to write a program that writes the pound sign '£' in Haskell, but it outputs '\163' whenever I try to use it. I'm guessing that this is some alphanumeric code, but how do I get it to display what I want it to? I'm writing to the console, when calling a function that returns '£'.

Thank you.

Comment: What code are you using? Is your terminal capable of displaying non-ASCII characters?

Comment: `pennies2pounds :: Int -> String`

`pennies2pounds pennies = "£" ++ show pounds ++ "." ++ show pence`

                 `where`

                   `(pounds, pence) = divMod pennies 100`

I'm using ghci to load the program in command prompt on Windows, and then calling pennies2pounds with integers.

Comment: You might be `show`ing or `print`ing strings, which adds extra quotes and escapes all non-ASCII characters. In GHCi, if you just want to output a string, use `putStrLn (the string-returning expression)`. E.g. `putStrLn (pennies2pounds 100)`

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I never knew `print` and `show` escapes non-ASCII characters.

Comment: `print` calls `show`, and the latter always outputs an ASCII string, representing values as done by Haskell's syntax. So, `show "abc" == "\"abc\""`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by using putStrLn, because `print` and `show` do not allow for non-ASCII characters to be shown.

Comment: More to the point, `show` and `print` take a value which is an instance of `Show` and returns or outputs a Haskell expression that evaluates to that value, in this case a `Char` whose `ord` is 163.